# Which layout should I use so my app looks like Google Plus?

Tags: android, listview, layout, gridview, grid-layout

I'd like to make a layout similar to the one used in the current version of Google Plus:

[image]

I don't know which layout I must use because :
 - I can't use a GridView because it doesn't support spanning row.
 - I can't use a GridLayout nor LinearLayout because the number of elements to show is dynamic
 - I can't use a ScrollView because I want an AdapterView to re-use child elements
 - I can use a ListView with two differents cells types but I can't use the built-in OnItemClickListener.

Do you have better ideas than me?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I do not see a reason not to use Linear Layout.. or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't want to use LinearLayout inside ScrollView because I want to use an AdapterView to re-use views.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use LinearLayout containing 5 fragments? Fragments exists mostly to be reused. I mean, the adapter may be not needed then

Comment: When I say that I have dynamic content I mean that I don't know how much items I have in my content exactly as Google Plus Stream

Comment: OK, this may be worth writing in the question. I'm sure someone will know how to, too bad i can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439544) suggested that it uses [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) . I personally haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well use `RelativeLayout` for this.
With a single `Relative Layout` you should be able to create exactly same layout.
Additionally, your content can be dynamically added to `Relative Layout` pretty easily (by setting proper `LayoutParams` to the content to be added).

Comment: Yes, but in this case we don't use an AdapterView which is very important for me

Comment: You can use AdapterView with RelativeLayout. Could you clarify your requirement more?