# Google Now-like asymmetrical grid on tablet

Tags: android, gridview, height, asymmetric, google-now

Does anybody have an idea how was a gridview with items of uneven height implemented?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a `StaggeredGridView`.
See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436359/android-column-gridview-variable-width-like-googleplus-app).

You can find an implementation at [github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

Comment: yea it is, I bet you that it will get announced now at IO.